# PHPUnit: is it possible to inject a mock into code not in a function?

Tags: mocking, phpunit

Say I have some PHP code outside of a function:

```
<?php
// some code
SomeClass::some_function();
?>
```

Is it possible to mock `some_function`?

Currently my test code is as follows:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
             ->setMethods(array('some_function'))
             ->getMock();
$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('some_function');
```

But I have no clue how to inject this into the previous code. Is it even possible? If not, how is one supposed to test something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

To test this code, you would actually call the page in a browser and make sure that things work correctly.  Code like this doesn't get mocked.  The test for code like this would be more along the lines of a "integration" test.

To test this code, you would need an additional tool along with PHPUnit like Selenium.
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-selenium-web-driver-api-with-phpunit/